# Why do STL implementations not use assertions to detect undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, stl, assert

This is something that I feel could come in useful but that I have not seen implemented in gcc's standard library.

Basically, it would seem to me that STL implementations could add assertions to detect (at runtime) simple errors like out-of-bound access. I'm guessing that these accesses are undefined behaviour in the standard anyhow, so surely printing an error message and -optionally- aborting would be standard compliant.

These assertions could of course be turned off at compile time through the old NDEBUG flag or some other flag.

As a small example, I would like this code to abort:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    return std::vector<int>{1,2}[2];
}
```

By the way, I am fully aware of the existence of tools like valgrind, but this could be a bonus. Also a memory checking tool like valgrind is not guaranteed to detect certain errors like access to an out-of-bounds element after a vector has been shrunk in size, since the implementation might not reallocate the underlying memory immediately.

Comment: Which implementations don't? GNU does if you define `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, and I believe Visual C++ does with suitable debug settings.

Comment: Does `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` not work for you?

Comment: It does... I was not aware of this flag... and my google-fu failed me apparently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This is something that I feel could come in useful but that I have not seen implemented in gcc's standard library.

You're wrong, try defining `_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`, which makes your example abort:

```
/home/jwakely/gcc/5/include/c++/5.0.0/debug/vector:402:error: attempt to 
    subscript container with out-of-bounds index 2, but container only 
    holds 2 elements.

Objects involved in the operation:
sequence "this" @ 0x0x7fffb8b221a0 {
  type = NSt7__debug6vectorIiSaIiEEE;
}
Aborted (core dumped)
```

> These assertions could of course be turned off at compile time through the old NDEBUG flag or some other flag.

The reason this uses a separate mechanism and not `assert()` and `NDEBUG` is because the checking adds overhead, so it is only enabled when explicitly requested. This means that users can continue to use `assert()` for their own checks without turning on the overhead of the standard library checking. There are also binary compatibility issues to be aware of with libstdc++'s debug mode, due to additional data members used to track iterator validity. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html for details.

Libc++ has similar checks as well, using a different macro, and VC++ enables similar checks automatically in debug builds.

Comment: But apparently, the libc++ one does not work yet. http://libcxx.llvm.org/debug_mode.html